# Email concept in codeigniter

Tags: php, email

I am a beginner need to send `email verification link` to all who filling the registration form. But I get the error like this:
Unable to send email using PHP `mail()`. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

```
Date: Thu, 17 May 2018 11:29:31 +0530
From: "Mydomain" <kumarinfo89@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <kumarinfo89@gmail.com>
Reply-To: <kumarinfo89@gmail.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: kumarinfo89@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 5 (Lowest)
Message-ID: <5afd1a436d57c@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

in the above I am getting the same email for sender and reply to u can see that above. I have tried changing of `"\n" into "\r\n"` and also tried changing of 587 to 465, as well as on php.ini in dds. any help i am sruggling more than a week

Answer (score 0):

```
configuration

    First of all paste the downloaded condeigniter directory inside server directory(e.g. for XAMPP xampp->htdocs folder)

    config codeigniter database connection in 

codeiniter->application->config->database.php
```

/* local server */

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'company',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

create Employee table inside company database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Before create sending email functions, open php>php.ini file and find 'extension=php_openssl.dll' then remove the semicolon at the begining of the line. Once done that restart the server.

Configure email settings

```
//config email settings
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = $from;
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '******';  //sender's password
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = 'TRUE';
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; 

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);


//send email
        $this->email->from($from);
        $this->email->to($receiver);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);

        $this->email->send()
```

https://github.com/kasunbuddhima/codeigniter-signup-form-with-email-verification

Comment: i have done it but no use. it showing as Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method. the sender email and to email both are resulting same for me